# Can I find exact match using phpQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, phpquery

I made a script using phpQuery. The script finds td's that contain a certain string:

```
$match = $dom->find('td:contains("'.$clubname.'")');
```

It worked good until now. Because one clubname is for example Austria Lustenau and the second club is Lustenau. It will select both clubs, but it only should select Lustenau (the second result), so I need to find a td containing an exact match.

I know that phpQuery are using jQuery selectors, but not all. Is there a way to find an exact match using phpQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: It is possible, see the answer from @ pguardiario

---

*Original answer. (at least an alternative):*

No, unfortunately it is not possible with phpQuery. But it can be done easily with **XPath**.

Imagine you have to following HTML:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<html>
  <head><title>test</title></head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>Hello World</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
EOF;
```

Use the following code to find exact matches with DOMXPath:

```
// create empty document 
$document = new DOMDocument();

// load html
$document->loadHTML($html);

// create xpath selector
$selector = new DOMXPath($document);

// selects all td node which's content is 'Hello'
$results = $selector->query('//td[text()="Hello"]');

// output the results 
foreach($results as $node) {
    $node->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

However, if you really need a phpQuery solution, use something like this:

```
require_once 'phpQuery/phpQuery.php';

// the search string
$needle = 'Hello';

// create phpQuery document
$document = phpQuery::newDocument($html);

// get matches as you suggested
$matches = $document->find('td:contains("' . $needle . '")');

// empty array for final results
$results = array();

// iterate through matches and check if the search string
// is the same as the node value
foreach($matches as $node) {
    if($node->nodeValue === $needle) {
        // put to results
        $results []= $node;
    }
}

// output results
foreach($results as $result) {
    echo $node->nodeValue . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was the solution I was looking for! I changed it a little bit to my own further needs and now it is perfect!

Comment: Another important notice: it is not possible to find an exact match only with phpQuery like you can do with jQuery filter function

Comment: Ah ok. I was not sure but thought this too. Thatswhy I used a second foreach loop for that (should be more or less the same)...

Comment: Not by me.. no reason for that

Comment: Would really like to know the reason, I cannot find one.

Comment: It was me, sorry. I showed that it can be done therefore your answer is wrong.

Comment: Ok, that's a reason, Have update post (But not validated it, I **hope** you are right!! ;) )

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with filter, but it's not pretty:

```
$dom->find('td')->filter(function($i, $node){return 'foo' == $node->nodeValue;});
```

But then, neither is switching back and forth between css and xpath

Answer (score 1):

I've no experience of phpQuery but the jQuery would be something like this :

```
var clubname = 'whatever';
var $match = $("td").map(function(index, domElement) {
    return ($(domElement).text() === clubname) ? domElement : null;
});
```

The phpQuery documentation indicates that `->map()` is available and that it accepts a callback function in the same way as in jQuery.

I'm sure you will be able to perform the translation into phpQuery.

**Edit**

Here's my attempt based on 5 minutes' reading - probably rubbish but here goes :

```
$match = $dom->find("td")->map(function($index, $domElement) {
    return (pq($domElement)->text() == $clubname) ? $domElement : null;
});
```

**Edit 2**

Here's a [demo of the jQuery version](http://jsfiddle.net/Fhm8K/).

If phpQuery does what it says in its [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), then (correctly translated from javascript) it should match the required element in the same way.

**Edit 3**

After some more reading about the [phpQuery callback system](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Callbacks), the following code stands a better chance of workng :

```
function textFilter($i, $el, $text) {
    return (pq($el)->text() == $text) ? $el : null;
}};
$match = $dom->find("td")->map('textFilter', new CallbackParam, new CallbackParam, $clubname);
```

Note that `->map()` is preferred over `->filter()` as `->map()` supports a simpler way to define pararameter "places" (see Example 2 in the referenced page).

Comment: Gijsve, the documentation suggests that my code should work but I don't have the means to test this stuff. Did you try it and if so what was the outcome?

Comment: Map is really a different concept than filter. Filter reduces the returned value, map just rewrites it.

Comment: That's not quite correct @pguardiario. `.map()` is certainly different from `.filter()` but not as you describe. As the jQuery documentation for `.map()` says "pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return values". Therefore `.map()` is a very flexible device, which returns a jQuery-wrapped array of whatever its callback returns. By *selectively* returning the original jQuery object's DOM elements, `.map()` behaves very much like `.filter()`, but with the ability to apply very specific filtering rules, as above.

Comment: Filter can do those same things. You're using map when you should be using filter and, as a result, you're getting a bunch of unnecessary nulls in your result. In other words, use map when you need to transform the elements (map them into something else), and filter when you are trying to reduce (filter) the result set.

Comment: @Gijsve, see my Edit 3. Please try it. I would like to know if it works.

Comment: @pguardiario, with reference to the documentation for `.map()` you will learn that by returning `null` (or `undefined`) from .map's callback, **no element will be inserted**, and we can only assume that phpQuery honours jQuery in this regard. Yes `.filter(callback)` will do the job but that doesn't mean `.map()` won't. It's a question of preference, not should/shouldn't.

Comment: No. jQuery's implementation may have confused you to the difference bteween map and filter, but they _are_ separate concepts. Btw, this isn't just a jQuery thing, many languages have map/filter (php has array_map vs array_filter) in case that's some extra incentive for you to start using them properly.

Comment: I've tried to explain. This is the point at which I give up before my blood boils.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I've written a function based on answer from [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl)

```
<?php

// phpQuery contains function

/**
* phpQuery contains method, this will be able to locate nodes
* relative to the NEEDLE
* @param string element_pattern
* @param string needle
* @return array
*/
function contains($element_pattern, $needle) {

    $needle = (string) $needle;
    $needle = trim($needle);

    $element_haystack_pattern = "{$element_pattern}:contains({$needle})";
    $element_haystack_pattern = (string) $element_haystack_pattern;

    $findResults = $this->find($element_haystack_pattern);

    $possibleResults = array();

    if($findResults && !empty($findResults)) {
        foreach($findResults as $nodeIndex => $node) {
            if($node->nodeValue !== $needle) {
                continue;
            }
            $possibleResults[$nodeIndex] = $node;
        }
    }

    return $possibleResults;

}

?>
```

Usage

```
<?php

$nodes = $document->contains("td.myClass", $clubname);

?>
```